# How do I Get the cummulative total of equation in MySql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySql statement, I cannot get the cummulative total for 'ranking' in my while loop

```
SELECT *,
    q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)
    AS ranking
    / SUM(ranking)
    FROM table
    WHERE field = :field
    GROUP by id
```

This part of my query works perfectly:

```
q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)
    AS ranking
```

I need to divide the 'AS ranking' value by the sum of each 'ranking' row in the query output and return it in the $rankingPercentage variable in my while loop.

`q1` `q2` `q3` `q4` `q5` `q6` are all fields in one table and contain number values (VARCHAR) between 0 and 100.

I expect to return an output for $rankingPercentage that is 'ranking' (my equation above "AS ranking") divided by the sum of all the 'ranking' rows returned in the SQL query.

My While loop below:

```
 while($row = $sqlprep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

        $ranking = $row->ranking;

        echo '<tr valign="bottom"><td>' . $row->id . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->uid . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->q1 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->q2 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->q3 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->q4 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->q5 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->q6 . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->q9 . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="capitalise">' .  $ranking. '</td>';
        echo '<td class="capitalise">' .  $rankingPercentage . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: Normalisation, perhaps?

Comment: @Strawberry Can you elaborate please?

Comment: No. I couldn't. But others might.

Comment: You should be clearer about the structure of your data and what you expect the output to be. This would be helped by an example showing both the table data and expected return values. Without a better explanation I can only guess that maybe you are looking for `SUM(q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)) AS ranking`

Comment: @nnichols Thanks I have edited my question, might be clearer now

Comment: @Grant - you have not added any detail of your data structure, sample data or expected output. As pointed out by Strawberry it does look horribly un-normalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you have a formula to assign a score per row, and then you need to see what portion of the total score across all rows this row earns.

A sub-select will solve this, though a join would probably be more efficient.

```
SELECT
    *,
    <formula> AS ranking
    <formula> / (
        SELECT SUM(<formula>) 
        FROM table
        WHERE field = :field
    ) AS rankingPercentage
FROM table
WHERE field = :field
GROUP BY id
```

This will tell you what part of the whole each row owns, it will not tell you that a given row is in the top X%.

Comment: Looks like you have solved it! I have added: ORDER by rankingPercentage DESC